# Version control software

Tags: php, version-control, phpmyadmin, version

I am researching about Version Control Software

There are many tools available but I have a question.

Is there any way that can control code and database at the same time?

Something like, when I change some code sometimes I need to change the database. Is there any way to control both and if I want, rollback to another version?

I am asking because we use PHP and MySQL (phpmyadmin) and it will be nice to have control to everything

Comment: I'm afraid this question will be considered off topic here, as it is asking mainly about recommendations about a software/tool.

Comment: I am not asking about a software or a tool. I am asking if is there a way to make it possiblme. 
I may have expressed myself poorly

Comment: https://dbmstools.com/version-control-tools

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/

Comment: @Jeff ... nice one, thanks.

Comment: @Jeff , thanks :) So, what I understand is that if I need to take control of code and database, I need to do it separately correct? The only way to integrate everything is creating something like a schema (in project folder) and have the schema updated in order to track all changes all the time? And if I change database, I update the schema and it saves like the change like code

Comment: I am using pure PHP. Maybe if I use a framework like laravel it would be easier to track everything right?

Comment: _"if I use a framework like laravel it would be easier"_ - possibly, yes. But I don't know if laravel includes db management.

Comment: @Jeff , I believe Laravel has Eloquent as ORM. And I have an idea that I read something about. But the problem persists, because where I work we don't use any framework :(